# jquery animation loop and pause

Tags: jquery, loops, animation, mouseenter, mouseleave

You can see here, while overing a pile of images, the animation that I'm trying to create. The animation is correct, but :

- I'm want this to be a loop : when the mouse enter, the animation starts, and when the mouse leaves, the animation **pause**. When the mouse enter again, the animation needs to continue (not start from the beginning). At the end of the animation, it needs to loop.

I hope I'm being clear.

Jsfiddle :

```js
$('figure').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).delay(0).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(1)').css({
            'z-index': '1',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(2)').css({
            'z-index': '1',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(3)').css({
            'z-index': '1',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(4)').css({
            'z-index': '1',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(5)').css({
            'z-index': '1',
        });
        next();
    });

    // reverse it
    $(this).delay(0).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(4)').css({
            'z-index': '2',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(3)').css({
            'z-index': '3',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(2)').css({
            'z-index': '4',
        });
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).find('img:nth-child(1)').css({
            'z-index': '5',
        });
        next();
    });
});
```

```css
 figure {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: block;
}

 figure img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    margin: auto;
}


 figure img:nth-child(1) {
    width: 60%;
    z-index: 5;
}

 figure img:nth-child(2) {
    width: 70%;
    z-index: 4;
}

 figure img:nth-child(3) {
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 3;
}

 figure img:nth-child(4) {
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#main figure img:nth-child(5) {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
    <a>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/efefef/">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/c7c7c7/">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/9b9b9b/">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/ff0000/">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/2b2b2b/">
    </a>
</figure>
```

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: May I suggest making a jsfiddle so we can play with it?

Comment: Just added. Sorry I should have done it earlier.